# Swap add to cart to Download Button when logged in [Wordpress/Woocommerce]

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

everyone!

I’m currently building a woocommerce website for some digital products, like 3D models that i want to sell and i want to implement a function that when a customer is on page of the product that they already bought, it should display Download button instead of Add to cart button. Do you guys have any idea how I could do that?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried to implement the following code into functions.php but without any result.

```
function wc_custom_replace_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product ) {
if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && $product->is_downloadable() ) {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() ) ) {
$button_text = __("Download", "woocommerce");
$button = '' . $button_text . '';
}
}
return $button;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'wc_custom_replace_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Do products have a single download file?

Comment: Yes, they do have a single download file.